# This question seems to have been edited by a user with 1 reputation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, specific-question

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327002/which-is-faster-in-python-x-5-or-math-sqrtx) on SO.com seems to have had its text edited by a user with 1 reputation. What's going on?

Comment: He's got about 9000 in rep.

Comment: Is it Over 9000?

Comment: Must be the jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user has a lot more rep, but was subsequently [suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) until next year so his rep has been artificially set to 1. If you're really interested in what happened, you can find a lot more info about him here on MSO.

Note that this can also happen if the user has enough rep at the time of editing, but is severely downvoted.

Comment: I just realized that there is no [rich-b] tag yet! Corrected.

Comment: Can he be named?

Comment: @Ólafur: [apparently not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/47568/revisions).

Comment: DUN DUN DUUUUN!